# 'timestamp' object has no attribute 'index'

Tags: python, pandas, join, timestamp

I am trying to join two dataframes in python pandas together by a date column.

How can you join two dataframes : df and a timestamp ?

It's giving me this error below. I am trying to have both date columns of the df and the dt dataframes to be named "Date" so I could join them.

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4767, in join
    rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4797, in _join_compat
    can_concat = all(df.index.is_unique for df in frames)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4797, in <genexpr>
    can_concat = all(df.index.is_unique for df in frames)
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'index'
```

I tried an alternative way of joining to change the timestamp dataframe
to a non-timestamp dateframe. It didn't work.

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd

# vars section
fields = ['Date','Adj Close']


# setup the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("SRS.csv", na_values=["0"],
                 parse_dates=["Date"])
df.to_csv('new.csv', index=True, columns=fields)

#data cleaner
df = df.fillna(0)
df = df[df.Date != "1970-01-01"]


# set the dataframes
dt = pd.date_range("08-11-2014","08-27-2014", index=True)
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(dt, index=True)

# print the dataframes
print(df)
print(idx)
print(dt)

# join the dataframes
df2 = df.join(dt, how='inner')
```

Comment: `dt` is not a dataframe. It is an index. You can convert it to a DataFrame with `pd.DataFrame(dt)`. Is it what you want?

Comment: I guess if it gets me to my goal of merging two dataframes. I need to construct the dt index in order to have a day count.  I know with any language there is multiple ways of accomplishing the same goal as I am just starting out with python. This works for now till I find something more efficient. Thanks.